# Is the FME Extension for ArcGIS required in order to use arcpy scripts in FME?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, fme-form, license

Is the **[FME Extension for ArcGIS](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/How_To/FME-ArcGIS-Extension)** required in order to use arcpy scripts in FME? I dont think it is but when i run a simple startup/shutdown script in FME I am getting these error messages.

[image]

[image]

This [article](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Error_Unexpected_Behavior/Some-Python-modules-generate-Runtime-Error-in-FME?popup=true) makes no mention of any known issues with the FME Extension for ArcGIS.

I am running FME 2013 SP2 (32bit) and ArcGIS 10.1 on a 64bit machine. A custom python intepreter has been set for FME [C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python27.dll]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem running arcpy from within FME. We do it in our [FME (Esri) training course](http://www.safe.com/learning/training/resource-center/fme-esri/). There are a number of things you need to do:

1. Have "import arcpy" in your Python script (obviously!)
2. If the version of Python is different (say ArcGIS is v2.6 and FME is v2.7) change the interpreter using Tools > FME Options > Runtime in Workbench
3. We also set PYTHONPATH environment variable, so FME can locate the arcpy libraries

   C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\bin;C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy;C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\ArcToolbox\Scripts

The FME Extension for ArcGIS is something you can activate in ArcGIS when you have FME, but it has no bearing on running a Python script in FME.

Comment: Modifying the ***Path*** variable (removing references to FME) seems to fix the problem. Also have PYTHONPATH set.

Answer (score 1):

If arcpy makes direct calls to esri software then FME must have access to the license for that software.  The only way to do that is register the software with FME (via esri extension or greater).
While not a direct answer to your question because I don't know what you are starting up and shutting down with arcpy. I am assuming it is esri software.
[Here is an FME article on compatibility](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Notes-on-FME-and-ESRI-Versions-and-Compatibility)
[This link has a users startup script wanting to use a specific esri license type](http://fmepedia.safe.com/AnswersQuestionDetail?id=906a0000000cgTFAAY)
[This link is to an FME document describing startup and shutdown procedures](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Using-a-Python-Startup-Shutdown-Script-to-Perform-Geoprocessing-with-Arcpy) also includes link to Article Number: 000002458

Answer (score 1):

I think this explains your first error: [FMEpedia Article Number: 000002458 modified June 2013](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Error_Unexpected_Behavior/Some-Python-modules-generate-Runtime-Error-in-FME?popup=true)

Basically, FME 2013 and arcpy are not compatible at the time of the article's writing. I'm not sure if that has changed.

The FME Extension for ArcGIS has nothing to do with calling arcpy from FME startup/shutdown scripts.